# how to get data from mapping using 2 parameters?

Tags: mapping, solidity

How to get the data from mapping with two parameters to trace the the matchSelected by address?
Full source:https://github.com/laronlineworld/bettingMatch/blob/main/bettingMatch.sol

```
 address[] public players;

   address public owner;
   
   
   
   struct Bet {
      uint256 amountBet;
      uint16 matchSelected;
      uint16 resultSelected;
    //   address[] players;
   }
   
   struct Player {
      uint256 amountBet;
      uint16 matchSelected;
      uint16 resultSelected;
      uint numFunders;
      mapping (uint => Bet) Bets;
   }
   mapping(uint16 => bool) matchBettingActive;

   mapping(address => Player) public playerInfo;
```

This is my getter function:

```
function getPlayerMatchInfo(address account, uint16 _matchSelected) public view returns (uint256, uint16, uint16, uint){
    return (playerInfo[account].amountBet, playerInfo[account].matchSelected, playerInfo[account].resultSelected, playerInfo[account].numFunders);

}
```

How to check the data by address and matchSelected?

Answer (score 0):

For the first return (I guess you want to return `amountBet`) You must do like this `playerInfo[account].Bets[NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK].amountBet`

So let me describe what happened.

When you call `playerInfo` it calls a mapping so you have to specify a address to access `Player` struct so you call `playerInfo[account]`

When you call `playerInfo[account]` it returns the struct:

```
      uint256 amountBet;
      uint16 matchSelected;
      uint16 resultSelected; 
      uint numFunders; 
      mapping (uint => Bet) Bets;}
```

So to access `Bets` You should do this `playerInfo[account].Bets` This returns a mapping! So to access `Bet` struct, You should give him argument.

`playerInfo[account].Bets[NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK]`

And finally to access `amountBet` You should do this `playerInfo[account].Bets[NUMBER_YOU_WANT_TO_CHECK].amountBet`

Syntax is this